# Корректно ли употреблять «донестись» с предлогом «на»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Корректно ли употреблять «донестись» с предлогом «на»? В Нацкорпусе нашлось 5 вхождений «донестись на» (что-либо) и 409 вхождений «донестись до». Например:

> ―…сы-ы! ― донеслось на берег. ― Тру-сы спали-и! [Василий Шукшин. Митька Ермаков (1970-1974)]

И все-таки такое малое количество примеров меня не убеждает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Грамматически* это вполне возможно, если предлог "на" сочетается с местом (берег, улица, этаж и т. п.). Но стилистически это редко бывает оправданным. Традиционно выражения с этим словом подразумевают *слуховое восприятие* звука персонажем или автором и указывают либо на источник (если персонаж ясен) - **откуда**, либо на персонажа - **до кого**. При указании же на *конечное место*, куда звук доносится (**на улицу** из какого-то шумного дома), возникает неопределённость относительно того, кто же это услышал: автор как бы берёт на себя ответственность за обобщение, что **все**, кто там был, должны были слышать нечто доносившееся неизвестно откуда. Необходимость такого описания возникает редко, и она нестандартна, на что и указывает статистика.

Comment: *все, кто там был, должны были слышать* — я бы сказал "могли слышать". А по сути согласен с ответом.